# I am unable to set the state to an initial value

Tags: reactjs

I am sharing a screenshot of my code, I have access to my books variable through props object. But, when I am assigning the initial state of a variable(nowBooks) I am getting an empty array. Why is that happening?

[image: Please help me out why data is showing as an empty array for line number 7 in BookList.js]

Comment: Post code, not screenshots of code please. In addition to the code for the component you've screenshotted above, you'll also want to post the code where you're using the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can arise if the parent component of `BookList` initially renders with no books, since `useState` only sets the initial value when the component is first rendered. If the parent component updates and there are now books in the list, that updated list will properly get passed into `BookList` which is why line 5 outputs the correct value. However, the state in `BookList` is never getting updated with the new list since the parent component never calls `updateNowBooks`. To fix this, you should keep the state for the current list of books in a single component (probably best to put it in the parent component here). From here, you pass the set function from the parent to `BookList`. Now, whenever you want to update the list of books from `BookList`, you call the set function passed in from the parent, and you will just use `props.books` to get the current list of books. Something like:

```
const BookList = function (props) {
    const currentBookList = props.books;
    const getUpdatedBookList = (updatedBooksAfterDeletion) => {
        props.setBooks(updatedBooksAfterDeletion);
    }

    ...
}
```

This will trigger a state update in the parent component which may also be useful for updating other parts of the UI.